# Swift - User Defaults not loading array of strings when app is launched

Tags: arrays, swift, string, append, userdefaults

So I have an app for a Midwestern car game where you count cows when you're driving and when you see a cemetery you lose half your cows. Whenever someone sees a cemetery, I have an emoji appear as an appended array of string, so they keep adding up. My problem is I can save the array to user defaults and it will print it correctly, but whenever I relaunch the app, the array goes back to a blank array of strings. So I know the data is saved correctly, just not loading when the app launches.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var playerOneNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfCowsPlayerOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerOneCows: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerOneCemeteries: UILabel!
  
    
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
   
    var cemeteryEmoji: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "CemeteryEmoji")! as? [String] ?? []
```

It will also strangely load the correct array in the field for display, but will start over any time a new cemetery is added:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if userDefaults.value(forKey: "CemeteryEmoji") != nil{
            playerOneCemeteries.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "CemeteryEmoji")!)"
            print(cemeteryEmoji)
        }else {
            playerOneCemeteries.text = ""
        }
    
    }
```

And here's the function for all the cemetery data:

```
@IBAction func playerOneCemetery(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let cemeteryCows = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "TotalCows") / 2
        self.userDefaults.set(cemeteryCows, forKey: "TotalCows")
        print(cemeteryCows)
        self.numberOfCowsPlayerOne.text = "\(self.userDefaults.string(forKey: "TotalCows")!) cows"
        

        addCemeteryEmoji()
        
        print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "CemeteryEmoji")!)
        
        
        func addCemeteryEmoji() {
            
            cemeteryEmoji.append("")
            print(cemeteryEmoji)
            self.playerOneCemeteries.text = "\(cemeteryEmoji.joined())"
            userDefaults.set(cemeteryEmoji.joined(), forKey: "CemeteryEmoji")
             
        }
    }
```

So I'm not sure if it's an issue simply when the app loads or if I need to save it a different way (although as I said, that works perfectly fine with all the print statements). Any help would be great.

Comment: UserDefaults doesn't immediately write data to disk. It might be so that you abruptly terminate the app from Xcode and UserDefaults doesn't have a chance to perform the write. What happens if you send the app to the background first (e.g. by navigating to the home screen) and then terminate it a few seconds later? Does it still read nothing on the next launch?

Comment: That still starts back up with an empty array and resets everything.

Comment: In this case consider putting breakpoints in all places where you write to UserDefaults and check whether you accidentally write empty data on the app startup.

Comment: After going through it again with breakpoints, the user defaults read correctly everywhere EXCEPT the intial instance of cemeteryEmoji. Everywhere else I print the user defaults for the var, they work correctly. But whenever I try to print for the var itself before adding new cemeteries, it comes up empty. So it somehow just isn't reloading the top instance of the var when the app reloads. Or something along those lines. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you `join` the array right before saving it which creates a single string.

And when you relaunch the app  `object(forKey: "CemeteryEmoji")! as? [String]` fails.

I highly recommend to name the array more meaningful and use the dedicated API `array(forKey:)`.

Name the array in **plural** form and declare an empty array

```
var cemeteryEmojis = [String]()
```

In `viewDidLoad` load the array from `UserDefaults`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if let emojis = userDefaults.array(forKey: "CemeteryEmoji") as? [String] {
        playerOneCemeteries.text = "\(emojis.joined())"
        cemeteryEmojis = emojis
        print(cemeteryEmojis)
    } else {
        playerOneCemeteries.text = ""
    }
}
```

And delete `joined()` in the `set` line of `addCemeteryEmoji`

```
func addCemeteryEmoji() {       
    cemeteryEmojis.append("")
    print(cemeteryEmojis)
    self.playerOneCemeteries.text = "\(cemeteryEmojis.joined())"
    userDefaults.set(cemeteryEmojis, forKey: "CemeteryEmoji") 
}
```

Comment: @BenG94 Please mark it as an accepted answer then.